# exec statement in nested function make locals() empty?

Tags: python, python-2.7

### First

```
x = 30
def out():
    x = 50
    def inner():
        print x
        print locals()
    return inner
out()()    # print locals() output {'x': 50}
```

### Second

But when I use `exec` , the output of `print locals()` is empty

```
x =30
def out():
    x = 50
    def inner():
        print x
        print locals()
        exec 'print x' in globals(), locals()
    return inner
out()()    #  print locals() ouput {}
```

Does `exec` have any side effects to the output of `locals()` ?

Comment: Yes it does. the `exec` statement explicitly copies all variables found in `locals()` back to the function locals. In Python 3, where `exec` was made into a function instead of a statement, the above, corrected for print and exec syntax changes, works.

Comment: Can you explain why the second example's locals() is empty?

Comment: Because there is no more `x` in the local scope. It now exists solely in the enclosure of the function `inner`, while the locals scope is reset. To see what happens, add the following lines of code to your second function `inner`:
        `print(x, globals())`
        `print(inner.func_code.co_freevars, [a.cell_contents for a in inner.func_closure])`

@Kasramvd I do not think it is an exact duplicate though. It is related, that is for sure.

Comment: I am curious about something . Which step reset the locals scope and why?  At the mean time,  why `x` exist in the `locals()` in first example? Appreciate your patience! :)

Comment: calling on the `exec` statement resets the locals scope. This was disabled in Python 3, where `exec` was remodelled to be a function instead of a statement to enforce unambiguous behaviour. As to why it ever did so in the first place..I cannot answer you that. :(